# Whitespace artifacts with pyplot bar graph animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to animate a `quicksort` sorting algorithm with `pyplot` bar graphs, but when the input list is long (500+ items), there seem to be these whitespace artifacts when rendering the animation that stay even after saving as a gif.

[image: screenshot of animation]

This is the animation function I am using

```py
def animate(_list, generator, title, save, save_frames=1000):
    n = len(_list)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title(title)
 
    bar_rects = ax.bar(range(len(_list)), _list, align="edge",antialiased=False)  
    ax.set_xlim(0, n)
    ax.set_ylim(0, int(1.1*n))
    text = ax.text(0.01, 0.95, "", transform = ax.transAxes)
    iteration = [0]
    def _animate(array, rects, iteration):
        for rect, val in zip(rects, array):
            rect.set_height(val)
        iteration[0] += 1
        text.set_text(f"iterations: {iteration[0]}")
   
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func=_animate,
        fargs=(bar_rects, iteration), frames=generator, interval=5,
        repeat=False, save_count=save_frames)
    if save:
        writer = PillowWriter(fps=30)
        anim.save(title + ".gif", writer=writer)
    plt.show()  


def quicksortP(numberList: list, end: int = None, start: int = 0):
    yield numberList
    if end is None:
        end = len(numberList) - 1
    if start < end:
        pivotPos = yield from partition(numberList, start=start, end=end)
        yield from quicksortP(numberList, start=start, end=pivotPos - 1)
        yield from quicksortP(numberList, start=pivotPos + 1, end=end)

def partition(numberlist: list, start: int, end: int):
    pivot = numberlist[end]
    biggestpos = start - 1
    for i in range(start, end):
        if numberlist[i] <= pivot:
            biggestpos += 1
            numberlist[i], numberlist[biggestpos] = numberlist[biggestpos], numberlist[i]
            yield numberlist
    biggestpos += 1
    numberlist[biggestpos], numberlist[end] = numberlist[end], numberlist[biggestpos]
    yield numberlist
    return biggestpos

if __name__=="__main__":
    nums=list(np.random.randint(0,500,500))
    animate(nums,quicksortP(nums),"test",save=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So far you've only provided your `animate` function which takes some unknown arguments. Please provide enough code that we can simply copy it into an IDE and run it.

Comment: @jared I have updated the code to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your bars are too thin for the resolution you are saving at.  You could try increasing the figure size or dpi, but a better option might be to use `stairs` which draws the data as one big patch.

Note that it is not necessary to pass the `stairs` artist or `iteration` to the `_animate` function since `_animate` has access to all the variables within `animate`'s scope.

```
def animate(_list, generator, title, save, save_frames=1000):
    n = len(_list)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_title(title)
 
    stairs = ax.stairs(_list, fill=True)  
    ax.set_xlim(0, n)
    ax.set_ylim(0, int(1.1*n))
    text = ax.text(0.01, 0.95, "", transform = ax.transAxes)
    iteration = [0]
    
    def _animate(array):
        stairs.set_data(array)
        iteration[0] += 1
        text.set_text(f"iterations: {iteration[0]}")
   
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, func=_animate,
        frames=generator, interval=5,
        repeat=False, save_count=save_frames)
    if save:
        writer = PillowWriter(fps=30)
        anim.save(title + ".gif", writer=writer)
```

[image]